# get two common words from two string

Tags: java, string

How can I match words from string

```
input:
bcdaa
bcdca

output:
bcda

input:
iamaman
iamaboy

output:
iama
```

I did comparing with two string by this way

```
Set<String> set1= new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s1.split("(?!^)")));
set1.retainAll(Arrays.asList(s2.split("(?!^)")));
```

But, it didn't provide the correct result. Now, How can I achieve that ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your examples don't make it clear.  I think you mean to find the longest or all common sub-strings of two strings, but `bcda` is not part of both `bcdaa` and `bcdca`. Please clarify or correct this.  If you're trying to match all, then wouldn't the correct result of the first example be: `{b,c,d,a,bc,bcd,cd}`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: Knowing how you define the correct result would greatly help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820377/comparing-two-strings-in-java-character-by-character

Comment: @TylerAndFriends by common words like(bcda,bcda are common for 1st input and iama,iama) or by make it an anagram.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to compare word in the strings. For this you can split your first string using space as regex with String.split(), then you check if the second string contains that word using String.contains().
Like this:

```
String[] temp = string1.split(" ");
for(string x : temp){
if(string2.contains(x))System.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common string problem known as the longest common sub sequence. You can find more information about the problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem
Furthermore if you want the algorithm to solve it, you can find a solution here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence#Java
It's written in different languages, other than Java.

This solution is an example of dynamic programming algorithms, if you are interested in this category of algorithms. Hope you find this answer useful.

This is also a clearer and more straight forward solution from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence

```
public static String lcs(String a, String b) {
int[][] lengths = new int[a.length()+1][b.length()+1];

// row 0 and column 0 are initialized to 0 already

for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++)
        if (a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(j))
            lengths[i+1][j+1] = lengths[i][j] + 1;
        else
            lengths[i+1][j+1] =
                Math.max(lengths[i+1][j], lengths[i][j+1]);

// read the substring out from the matrix
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int x = a.length(), y = b.length();
     x != 0 && y != 0; ) {
    if (lengths[x][y] == lengths[x-1][y])
        x--;
    else if (lengths[x][y] == lengths[x][y-1])
        y--;
    else {
        assert a.charAt(x-1) == b.charAt(y-1);
        sb.append(a.charAt(x-1));
        x--;
        y--;
    }
}

return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
    String str1 = "bcdaa";
    String str2 = "bcdca";
    String strbuilder = "";

    char[] first = str1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] second = str2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    int minLength = Math.min(first.length, second.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        if (first[i] == second[i]) {
            strbuilder += String.valueOf(first[i]);

        }
    }
    System.out.println(strbuilder);
```