# How to check a String's character not matching with other character of another String

Tags: java

I have two Strings i.e

```
   String test1 = "If you want to succeed then work hard.Best of luck" .

   String test2 = "If you want to succeed then work hard.Best of Yuck" .
```

Basically , these are the dummy test strings i have taken for reference for here.In actually , i have strings which have more than 10000 lines of character.

I want to check where these strings are equal or not . I know .equals will compare both the strings value are return a boolean value. But i want to check at what character it didn't match.

I tried :-

```
for(int i=0 ; i<=test1.length();i++){
            for(int j=0 ; j<=test2.length();j++){
          if (test1.charAt(i)==test2.charAt(j)){
           System.out.println("Matched "+test1.charAt(i)+"  "+test2.charAt(j));
                }
          else{
        System.out.println("Not Matched "+test1.charAt(i)+"  "+test2.charAt(j));
            }
              } 
                }
```

But this code will check each character of test1 string with the every character of test2 and print.
I want to check each character of test1 with each character to test2.

Comment: @mins please read the question Liitle bird asked. He can not solve it using equals method

Comment: @Naz: My bad! Thanks and apologize to Little bird. Does this help (as a starter, it must be customized to your need): [Comparing two strings in java character by character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820377/comparing-two-strings-in-java-character-by-character).

Comment: @mins that was an awesome resource with different ways to implement for the above question. I would suggest Little bird to look over that

Answer (score 1):

You have `difference` method in [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) apache library. It will return portion of String where they are different.

Also you have couple more useful methods there (i.e. `indexOfDifference` which will return index where difference starts or `getLevenshteinDistance` which will return number of changes which need to be applied to one string so it is equal to other) so with combination of those you can probably get what you want.

Other option for more complicated usage can be external library (one that can help you is [java-dif-utils](https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/wiki/SampleUsage)).